# Typo3 condition with variable like lib

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need a variable from the setup in the typoscript condition like:

```
lib.test = TEXT
lib.test.value = 1

[lib.test == 1]
page.10.variables.CONTENT = TEXT
page.10.variables.CONTENT.value = done!
[END]
```

but it dont work as expected. I try'd different ways with {$lib.test} but this all means constants and i need it from the setup, is this possible and how?

Typo3 is V11

the condition always fail, the lib will be edited but for this question the scheme is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a TypoScript setup variable as a TypoScript condition in the same setup, since the **conditions will be considered during TypoScript parsing only**.

So there is no way to get the value of `lib.something` as an expression for the condition, since that value is not known at all before the TypoScript has been parsed.

Could you explain the use case a bit more to find out if there are other possible solutions for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Conditions are evil. You should avoid them whenever possible. They will eat up performance and make caching more difficult.

For your use-case, TypoScript's [`if`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Functions/If.html) should be a better way:

```
page.10.variables.CONTENT = TEXT
page.10.variables.CONTENT.value = done!
page.10.variables.CONTENT.if {
    equals = 1
    value.cObject = TEXT
    value.cObject.value = 1
}
```